# UIInputView not working as expected

Tags: ios7, keyboard, inputview

This might be a bug in iOS7..? When I add the accessoryview I use the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
UIView *inputAccView = [[UIInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 320, 50) inputViewStyle:UIInputViewStyleKeyboard];
```

That works as expected, background same as regular keyboard in iOS7. But when I use:

```
[textfield setInputView:[[UIInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 215) inputViewStyle:UIInputViewStyleKeyboard]];
```

It does now work, sometimes gives a transparent blurry background as seen in attached image, other times just returning a grey background. I have only run in simulator

I'm I doing something wrong or is this a bug?[image]

Comment: Are you sure about the size ? CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 215)  Coz on your viewDidLoad method it's different...

Comment: Updated from Xcode 5.02 to 5.1.1 and iOS 7.1, now it's working! Might have to look into iOS 7.0 compatibility later, when running on device.

Comment: Would you mind telling what's the alert you are using on the pic ? Is it a custom one or a built in one ?

Comment: You can find the library here:
https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController

Can really recommend it

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to have a the input view as a toolbar accessory to your uikeyboard, Shouldn't you be adding it as `[textField setInputAccessoryView:myInputView]`?

Comment: Didn't want it as an accessory view I wanted to have another keyboard